# Как отключить всплывающее окно с выбором превью в phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

[image: Как убрать?]

При наведении курсором на поле появляется это, если нужно я горячими клавишами воспользуюсь, как скрыть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **Preferences** перейдите **Tools > Web Browsers**. Снимите флажок **Для файлов HTML** в разделе **Показывать всплывающее окно браузера** в редакторе в нижней части окна. Нажмите кнопку **Применить**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему? К сожалению, PhpStorm показывает эти значки не только для файлов HTML, но и для файлов PHP. В большинстве CMS (например, WordPress) или фреймворках (например, Yii Framework или Zend Framework) это бесполезно. Вам нужно запустить свой фреймворк или CMS, чтобы увидеть, как на самом деле будет выглядеть этот PHP-шаблон. Но если вы нажмете на один из этих значков, PhpStorm откроет текущий файл в браузере (вместо запуска кода CMS или фреймворка для отображения соответствующей страницы).

Итак, в большинстве случаев, когда вы работаете с любой CMS или фреймворком на PHP, эти значки просто занимают место на экране.

Но если вы много работаете со статическими HTML-файлами, эти иконки, конечно, вам очень пригодятся.

[Источник](https://www.wpdiaries.com/phpstorm-settings/) с вариантами.